# full support iteration of semiproper forcings

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

Suppose $\langle P_\alpha,\dot{Q}_\alpha:\alpha\leq\omega_1\rangle$ is a full support iteration of (semi)proper forcings. Is the full limit $P_{\omega_1}$ (semi)proper or at least stationary set preserving?